# How to move auto generate Delete Button on right side in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview having following columns

```
Delete | Name | ContactNo | EmailID | CreateDate |
```

Delete column is auto generated, i want to move it on right side like

```
 | Name | ContactNo | EmailID | CreateDate | Delete
```

how can i do this???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**AutoGenerateDeleteButton** will not be visible at Design Time because the VS will automatically add it during Run-time and as far as I know this will be added automatically at the Left Most side of the Grid and basically that's by default.

You could try adding following command field in the design view.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

or else, you have to create a Button Template column for delete.

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all you cannot do this with the auto generated delete button, so you must set `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"`
2. Create a `CommandField` for the delete button and place it below all the other columns, that would make it appear on the right:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
        <asp:CommandField DeleteText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>{new Employee{Id="1",Name="Employee 1"}};
            gvEmployees.DataSource = employees;
            gvEmployees.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create a RowCreated Event on your grid... easy as that (this will swap the row to end,, no need to turn off auto generate... 100% worked for me)

 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = e.Row;
            // Intitialize TableCell list
            List<TableCell> columns = new List<TableCell>();
            foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
            {
                //Get the first Cell /Column
                TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
                // Then Remove it after
                row.Cells.Remove(cell);
                //And Add it to the List Collections
                columns.Add(cell);
            }
            // Add cells
            row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
        }
```